# pandas create boolean column using groupby transform

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to create a boolean column using `GroupBy.transform` on a `df` like this,

```
id    type
1     1.00000
1     1.00000
2     2.00000
2     3.00000
3     2.00000
```

the code is like,

```
df['has_two'] = df.groupby('id')['type'].transform(lambda x: x == 2)
```

but instead of boolean values, `has_two` has float values, e.g. `0.0`. I am wondering why is that.

UPDATE

I created a test case,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['1', '1', '2', '2', '3'], 'type':[1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0]})
df['has_2'] = df.groupby('id')['type'].transform(lambda x: x == 2)
```

this gave me,

```
   id  type  has_2
0  1   1.0    0.0
1  1   1.0    0.0
2  2   2.0    1.0
3  2   1.0    0.0
4  3   2.0    1.0
```

if I am using `df['has_2'] = df['type'] == 2` as suggested by `jezrael`, it is fine,

```
   id  type  has_2
0  1   1.0  False
1  1   1.0  False
2  2   2.0   True
3  2   1.0  False
4  3   2.0   True
```

I am using `pandas==0.20.3` on `Python 3.5.2`. I am wondering what's going on, do I need an update on `pandas` or `python 3`?

UPDATE

Updated `pandas` to `0.22.0` fixed this issue.

Comment: Why do you use `groupby`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thought it is convenient

Comment: Convenient for what task exactly?

Comment: I test it in pandas `0.21.1` and `0.22.0` and it working fine, so try upgrade pandas.

Comment: @ayhan thought I need something that can compare every element to 2 in a group by `id`

Comment: @jezrael updated `pandas` to `0.22.0`, the issue is now fixed, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it working nice, I get boolean column:

```
df['has_two'] = df.groupby('id')['type'].transform(lambda x: x == 2)
print (df)
   id  type  has_two
0   1   1.0    False
1   1   1.0    False
2   2   2.0     True
3   2   3.0    False
4   3   2.0     True
```

But maybe is possible only compare column:

```
df['has_two'] = df['type'] == 2
print (df)
   id  type  has_two
0   1   1.0    False
1   1   1.0    False
2   2   2.0     True
3   2   3.0    False
4   3   2.0     True
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this line

```
df['has_two'] = df.groupby('id')['type'].transform(lambda x: x == 2) == 2
```

Worked for me :)