# dataframe in pandas with certain conditions

Tags: python, pandas

am trying to combine features of in a dataframe to derive a new columns in the dataframe

I have this dataframe

```
Id   Author   News_post  Label
1    Jessica  xxxxxxxxx  1
2    Adams    xxxxxxxxx  1
3    Adams    xxxxxxxxx  1
4    Mike     xxxxxxxxx  0
5    James    xxxxxxxxx  1
6    Mike     xxxxxxxxx  1
7    Mike     xxxxxxxxx  0
8    Paul     xxxxxxxxx  0
9    Jessica  xxxxxxxxx  0
10   Adams    xxxxxxxxx  0
```

NB: where the `Label` column have `1=TRUE` AND `0=FALSE`

```
Id   Author   Num_Post  Num_True_Label  Num_False_Label   Mean
1    Adams    3         2               1                 x
2    James    1         1               0                 x
3    Jessica  2         1               1                 x
4    Mike     2         0               1                 x
5    Paul     1         0               0                 x
```

Comment: Duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum/39923815.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48059985/pandas-create-boolean-column-using-groupby-transform look here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas create boolean column using groupby transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48059985/pandas-create-boolean-column-using-groupby-transform)

Comment: your data doesn't make much sense, the ID's in the first df and 2nd df don't match?

Comment: the id's for the output does not matter. since the out is to create a new dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) and then remove the duplicates such that:

```
df['Num_Post']= df.groupby(['Author'])['Label'].transform('count')
df['Num_True_Label']= df.groupby(['Author'])['Label'].transform('sum')
df['Num_False_Label']= df['Num_Post']-df['Num_True_Label']
df['Mean']= df['Num_Post']/df['Num_True_Label']
```

Finally: drop dups and remove the News_post

```
df.drop(columns=['News_post'], inplace=True)
df.drop_duplicates(subset='Author', keep='first').sort_values(by=['Author'])
```

result:

```
    Id  Author      Label   Num_Post    Num_True_Label  Num_False_Label Mean
    1   2   Adams       1       3           2               1               1.500000
    4   5   James       1       1           1               0               1.000000
    0   1   Jessica     1       2           1               1               2.000000
    3   4   Mike        0       3           1               2               3.000000
    7   8   Paul        0       1           0               1               inf
```

Note: change the mean for your definition.

Comment: thanks, it works but the value of the resultis not correct. and the output does not need the column for News_Post because the column will show no significant in the output

Comment: just drop the column. see my edit (you can also drop the label with:  df.drop(columns=['News_post','Label'], inplace=True)

Answer (score 1):

This may solve a number of things you are trying to get from your issue:

```py
df = pd.read_clipboard()  # just copied your dataframe
df = df.groupby('Author').describe()
```

Output:

```
           Id                                               Label                                               
        count      mean       std  min  25%  50%  75%   max count      mean       std  min   25%  50%   75%  max
Author                                                                                                          
Adams     3.0  5.000000  4.358899  2.0  2.5  3.0  6.5  10.0   3.0  0.666667  0.577350  0.0  0.50  1.0  1.00  1.0
James     1.0  5.000000       NaN  5.0  5.0  5.0  5.0   5.0   1.0  1.000000       NaN  1.0  1.00  1.0  1.00  1.0
Jessica   2.0  5.000000  5.656854  1.0  3.0  5.0  7.0   9.0   2.0  0.500000  0.707107  0.0  0.25  0.5  0.75  1.0
Mike      3.0  5.666667  1.527525  4.0  5.0  6.0  6.5   7.0   3.0  0.333333  0.577350  0.0  0.00  0.0  0.50  1.0
Paul      1.0  8.000000       NaN  8.0  8.0  8.0  8.0   8.0   1.0  0.000000       NaN  0.0  0.00  0.0  0.00  0.0
```

Comment: i want the code that do exactly what my output shows. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following will get you what you need:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Author': ['Jessica', 'Adams', 'Adams', 'Mike', 'James', 'Mike', 'Mike', 'Paul', 'Jessica', 'Adams'], 'News_post': ['xxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxx', 'xx
    ...: xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxx'], 'Label': [1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0]})                                                                                                                                                                

In [3]: num_true_label_df = df.groupby(by=['Author']).sum().rename(columns={'Label': 'Num_True_Label'}).reset_index()                                                                                                                        

In [4]: num_post_df = df.groupby(by=['Author']).count().rename(columns={'News_post': 'Num_Post'})[['Num_Post']].reset_index()                                                                                                                

In [5]: df = pd.merge(num_post_df, num_true_label_df, how='left', on='Author').reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'Id'})

In [6]: df['Id'] = df['Id'] + 1

In [7]: df['Num_False_Label'] = df['Num_Post'] - df['Num_True_Label']

In [8]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[7]: 
   Id   Author  Num_Post  Num_True_Label  Num_False_Label
0   1    Adams         3               2                1
1   2    James         1               1                0
2   3  Jessica         2               1                1
3   4     Mike         3               1                2
4   5     Paul         1               0                1
```

Please further specify what your `Mean` column should represent.

Some resources which might be helpful:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Comment: the out does not give what i expected

Comment: Sorry, just fixed it, @umagbaalex

Comment: i tried using the code but i got this error: KeyError: 'Num Post'

Comment: From your comment, it seems that you were trying to access column 'Num Post', is that right? From the way I established the dataframe above, the column is actually called 'Num_Post' (notice the underscore between the words)

Comment: i tried to access column Num_Post. KeyError: 'Num_Post'

Comment: When is this error happening? (What's the line of code you're trying to run?)

Answer (score 1):

Using Pandas 0.25 with [aggregation relabeling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html#groupby-aggregation-with-relabeling)

```
df.groupby('Author')['Label'].agg(Num_Post = 'size',
                                  Num_True = 'sum',
                                  Num_False = lambda x: x.eq(0).sum(),
                                  Mean = 'mean')
```

Output:

```
         Num_Post  Num_True  Num_False      Mean
Author                                          
Adams           3         2          1  0.666667
James           1         1          0  1.000000
Jessica         2         1          1  0.500000
Mike            3         1          2  0.333333
Paul            1         0          1  0.000000
```

Comment: got this error: TypeError: aggregate() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: You need to upgrade to pandas 0.25.

Answer (score 0):

you could try :

```
agg_df = df.groupby('Author')['Label'].agg({"Num_post" : 'count', 'Num_True_Label' : 
                                             lambda x : x.eq(1).sum(), 
                                            'Num_False_Label':lambda x : 
                                            x.eq(0).sum(), 
                                            'Mean':'mean'}).reset_index()
```